# ASP.Net Core - Dynamically generate index.html

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core

The standard way to provide an index.html to the client with ASP.Net core is to use the middleware `app.UseStaticFiles();` on `IApplicationBuilder` instance in the `Configure` method of the `StartUp` class. This provides a static index.html file from the wwwroot folder. Is there a way to provide an index.html to the client, that is dynamically generated in code on request?

Comment: If you're dynamically generating the response, why use static files at all?  Why not something like Razor Pages or MVC?

Comment: In the end its for a Blazor wasm project, but with blazor I cannot modify the initally loaded index.html. Is it possible to provide a Blazor wasm with Razor Pages and still have wasm debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to change the SPA files content served from the static folder.

You should do the following:

1. update your usage of `UseStaticFiles`, it should have a lambda provided for the `OnPrepareResponse` property; See this [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.staticfileoptions.onprepareresponse?view=aspnetcore-6.0)
2. It is called every time the static file is returned to the client;
3. You can analyze the file name to ensure it is index.html;
4. Your code can completely change the content that will be returned. Just generate a file dynamically to replace index.html, and write it as a response body by writing to a stream. You might need to clear or save original body content before modifying and returning it if your writing has failed.

See code example to get you started:

```
var staticFileOptions = new StaticFileOptions
{
    OnPrepareResponse = context =>
    {
        // Only for Index.HTML file
        if (context.File.Name == "index.html") {
            var response = context.Context.Response;
            var str = "This is your new content";
            var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(str);
            // modified stream
            var responseData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString);
            var stream = new MemoryStream(responseData);
            // set the response body
            response.Body = stream;
        }
    }
};

app.UseStaticFiles(staticFileOptions);
```

Comment: You should include a code example or references to the relevant documentation, this should point them in the right direction, but the docs hold the specifics about how to implement the `OnPrepareResponse` which is the obvious follow up question to your post.

Comment: I don't think this works. From the doc you have linked:

"Called after the status code and headers have been set, but before the body has been written. This can be used to add or change the response headers."

Since the body hasn't been written yet anything you put into the body will be appended to. Using a MemoryStream results in this exception: `System.NotSupportedException: Memory stream is not expandable`

Comment: Doesn't work. When I update the response body in `onPrepareResponse`, I get no response data as a result.